# Vertically align labels with different font sizes, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I would like to vertically align labels with different font sizes, so that they appear sitting on a common baseline.

In this case, I have three labels embedded inside a stackview as you can see in the below picture. Number 30 appears to be clearly offset from the baseline, whereas text 'In' and 'MINUTES' appears to be offset too, but not significant. How can I get all three to be sitting on the same baseline ?

[image]

I am creating the labels and stack view programatically as you can see below:

```
var timeStackView           : UIStackView!
var timeIndication          : UILabel!
var time                    : UILabel!
var unitsOrTimeZone         : UILabel!

timeStackView = UIStackView()
timeStackView.addArrangedSubview(timeIndication)
timeStackView.addArrangedSubview(time)
timeStackView.addArrangedSubview(unitsOrTimeZone)
timeStackView.alignment = .bottom      // bottom alignment
timeStackView.axis = .horizontal
timeStackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
timeStackView.spacing = 10.0
```

All the three labels are created in a similar way as shown below, but with different text:

```
timeIndication                      =   UILabel()
timeIndication.textAlignment        =   .center
timeIndication.text                 =   "In"
timeIndication.font                 =   timeIndication.font.withSize(14)
timeIndication.baselineAdjustment   = .alignBaselines // baselineAdjustment
```

I have tried `timeStackView.alignment = .bottom` and `timeIndication.baselineAdjustment   = .alignBaselines`, but they don't seem to work.

Comment: y r u not using `attributedText`..with that u can put the full text with different sizes of text in the same `UILabel`

Comment: I am programatically changing the text of the text labels, I am not sure if I can do the same with attributedText

Comment: then use `MutableAttributedString` and make a function to which u can pass three strings... and append in the `MutableAttributedString`..use that appended `AttributedString` for ur `UILabel`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven‘t tried it, but according to the `UIStackView` documentation, you should set the stack view‘s alignment to either [`.lastBaseline`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackviewalignment/1616222-lastbaseline) or `.firstBaseline`, depending on how you want multiline labels to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI it is possible to achieve it by using: **.lastTextBaseline**

```
HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline) {
    Text("Hello")
        .font(.caption)
    Text("SwiftUI")
        .font(.subheadline)
}
```